# What can be an Alternative jar to tika-app jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, apache-tika

I am using **tika-app-1.9.0** jar currently in my java project.
But I want to replace tika-app with some other jar as tika-app has multiple vulnerabilities.

edit::I have tried latest version of tika as well but it also has vulnerabilities.

Is there any other alternative jar/jars which will help me use **httpentitty,mimetype,inputbuffer**,etc from tika-app?

Basically an alternative to tika-app?

Comment: Interesting. Have you every thought about updating it to a more recent version because 1.9.0 is about 5 years old... Take a look at https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-app ? Apart from that is: Do you use only httpentity etc. from the package or do you use tika itself?

Comment: I tried the latest version as well but it also has vulnerabilities. Not only httpentitty but also tika dependencies.

Comment: And which kind of ? Are they valid for your use case?

Comment: Try with a vaguely recent version of Apache Tika? 1.25 is out and works fine, 1.26 will hopefully be out next week

Comment: to the text extraction you can use the pure tesseract (or tesseract + tess4j). But tika itself contains many features - and I m not sure is easy to be replaced